# Excel. Большее число разделить на меньшее

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Задача следующая: есть три ячейки, в каждой числовое значение(в первой ячейке - первое число, во второй ячейке - второе число, в третьей ячейке - результат). Есть ли какая-то формула, которая сравнит значения в первой и второй ячейке и большее число разделит на меньшее, а результат в третьей ячейке записывается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=МАКС(A1:B1)/МИН(A1:B1)

=ЕСЛИ(МАКС(A1:B1)=A1;A1/B1;B1/A1)

=МАКС(A1/B1;B1/A1)
```

Нужна еще проверка, чтобы не возникла ошибка деления на ноль:

```
=ЕСЛИ(МИН(A1:B1)=0;"ошибка";МАКС(A1:B1)/МИН(A1:B1))

=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(МАКС(A1:B1)/МИН(A1:B1);"нельзя!")
```